# if_else does not return NA as expected (returns false condition instead)

Tags: r, dplyr

I've seen a couple questions dance around this issue, but none seem to address it directly.

I have character data in a dataframe column, some values are `NA`.  The `if_else()` help file example demonstrates that it will leave `NA` as `NA` unless otherwise specified with the `missing` argument.

However, in my situation, it treats `NA` as if it met the `false` argument criteria, and returns it that way.  Is this expected behavior?  Is it due to working with character data?  I *am* able to see expected behavior from the **help file** code with integer data.

I have checked `str(my_df$test_vector)`, and it is character data, not factor data.

Thanks in advance to the forum gurus.

Example:

```r
> test_vector <- c("1dose", "2dose", "yes", "no", "undecided", NA) # data as it appears in my dataframe
> is.na(test_vector)  # behaves as expected
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE 
> if_else(test_vector %in% c("1dose", "2dose", "yes"), "yes", "no")  # does not behave as expected
[1] "yes" "yes" "yes" "no"  "no"  "no"
> if_else(test_vector %in% c("1dose", "2dose", "yes"), "yes", "no", NA_character_)  # also unexpected
[1] "yes" "yes" "yes" "no"  "no"  "no"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operator %in% returns false against the NA value:

```
test_vector %in% c("1dose", "2dose", "yes")
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I believe str_detect is going to give you the behavior you're looking for:

```
> if_else(str_detect(test_vector, c("1dose", "2dose", "yes")),"yes","no")
[1] "yes" "yes" "yes" "no"  "no"  NA
```

Comment: From the help for %in% - "That %in% never returns NA makes it particularly useful in if conditions."

Comment: Be wary that it is also dangerous. If used in sequential operations, you may artificially remove NAs

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you for picking out this detail.  I will be more diligent in checking all my intermediate steps!  It's easy to forget that %in% is playing major role when it's visually so small.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you found is related to the behaviour of the %in% operator, not the if_else() function. %in% returns FALSE when comparing anything to NA.

```
test_vector <- c("1dose", "2dose", "yes", "no", "undecided", NA)

> if_else(test_vector=='yes', 1, 0)
[1]  0  0  1  0  0 NA
```

```
> if_else(test_vector %in% 'yes', 1, 0)
[1] 0 0 1 0 0 0
```